# in unix system, replace string in file, with variouse position

Tags: string, unix, csv, replace

I work on unix server.
I have many csv files containing, among other info, date fields.

I have to replace some of this date fields with another value, for example **20110915** to **20110815**.  Their position is variable from a file to another.

The problem is that the substitution is position field specific.  For example, if my file has row like this:

*blablabla;12;0.2121;**20110915**;20110915;19951231;popopo;other text;321;20101010*

I have to replace only first date fields and not other, transforming row in:

*blablabla;12;0.2121;**20110815**;20110915;19951231;popopo;other text;321;20101010*

Is there a way to restrict the replace in file, using some constraints?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `awk`:

```
awk  'BEGIN {FS=";";OFS=";"} {if($4=="20110915")$4="20110815"; print}' input.csv
```

**How it works:**

`FS` and `OFS` define the input and output field separators. It compares the fourth field ($4) against `20110915`. If it matches, it is changed to `20110815`. The line is then printed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative using gsub in awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=";";OFS=";"} {gsub(/20110915/,20110815,$4); print}' input.csv
```

Here is a method, if you have to substitute in a range of fields/columns (e.g. 4-4):

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=";";OFS=";"} {for(i=4;i<=4;i++){gsub(/20110915/,20110815,$i)}; print}' input.csv
```